# Помогите составить алгоритм для горизонтального скролла

Tags: python, matplotlib

Здравствуйте.
Есть вот такой вот график:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне необходимо разобраться в том как работает аргумент в слайдере, для того что бы попытаться настроить код под себя.
В данном конкретном случае мне необходима реализация масштабирования на слайдере.
Что бы расстояние между точками по оси Y было либо огромным либо что бы все вообще в одну точку сливалось. Этого мне достичь удалось - но происходт это все в 2 шага почему то. И мне нужно понять почему.
Хотелось бы что бы это происходило плавно и масштабирование что бы можно было корректировать немного иначе..(крайние пределы)
Что только не пробовал уже - ничего на ум не приходит работающего корректно. )

Вопрос:
как это можно реализовать с помощью слайдера?
Мне необходимо, что бы масштабирование происходило по 2 значениям(самой высокой точке и самой низкой)

P.S. Cкелет некорректно работающего кода пока что так у меня выглядит:

```
        aycolor = 'blue'

        ax_y_pos = plt.axes([0.086, 0.894, 0.828, 0.022], axisbg=aycolor)

        y_pos = Slider(ax_y_pos, '', 0, 1, valfmt='%d', valinit=max_value(self.high) + (max_value(self.high) * 0.0022), color='green')

        y_pos.valtext.set_visible(False)

        def update(val):
            pos = int(y_pos.val)
            ax.set_ylim(min_value(self.low), max_value(self.high))
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()

        cid = y_pos.on_changed(update)

        ax.set_ylim(min_value(self.low) - (min_value(self.low) * 0.0022), max_value(self.high) + (max_value(self.high) * 0.0022))
```

Буду признателен за любую помощь..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить вопрос самостоятельно следующим образом:

```
        candlesticks_in_screen = 25
        start_slider_y = 0.1

        # вычисляем минимальный low среди свечек, которые помещаются в одном экране
        def min_value(self_low):

            self_low = self_low[-candlesticks_in_screen:]
            low_min_value = [self_low[0]]

            for search_min_value in self_low:
                if search_min_value < low_min_value[0]:
                    low_min_value.clear()
                    low_min_value.append(search_min_value)

            return low_min_value[0]

        # вычисляем максимальный high среди свечек, которые помещаются в одном экране
        def max_value(self_high):

            self_high = self_high[-candlesticks_in_screen:]
            high_max_value = [self_high[0]]

            for search_max_value in self_high:
                if search_max_value > high_max_value[0]:
                    high_max_value.clear()
                    high_max_value.append(search_max_value)

            return high_max_value[0]

        aycolor = 'orange'

        ax_y_pos = plt.axes([0.086, 0.894, 0.828, 0.022], axisbg=aycolor)

        y_pos = Slider(ax_y_pos, '', 0, 1, valfmt='%d', valinit=start_slider_y, color='green')

        y_pos.valtext.set_visible(False)

        def update(val):
            pos = int(y_pos.val)
            # print('pos = ', pos,'\n', 'val = ', val)
            ax.set_ylim(min_value(self.low) - (val / 100), max_value(self.high) + (val / 100))
            # print('\n', 'ax.set_ylim = ', ax.set_ylim(min_value(self.low) - (val / 100),
            #  max_value(self.high) + (val / 100)), '\n', 'val = ', val)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()

        cid = y_pos.on_changed(update)

        ax.set_ylim(min_value(self.low) - start_slider_y / 100, max_value(self.high) + start_slider_y / 100)

        # ----------    Slider(Scroll Bar)  Axex y   end   ------------------
```